# using template assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates

Having following code, why the first assignment doesn't call template `operator=` in `Foo`, but second does? What is going one here? Is there compiler-generated one for the first assignment even if user defined template exists?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct UberFoo { };

struct Foo : public UberFoo 
{
    template<typename T> void operator=(const T& v) { cout << "const T&" << endl; Set(v); }
    template<typename T> void operator=(T& v) { cout << "T&" << endl; return Set(v); }

    virtual void Set(const Foo&) { cout << "Foo::Set(const Foo&)" << endl; }
    virtual void Set(const UberFoo&) { cout << "Foo::Set(const UberFoo&)" << endl; }
};

struct Bar : public Foo 
{
    virtual void Set(const Foo&) { cout << "Bar::Set(const Foo&)" << endl; }
    virtual void Set(const UberFoo&) { cout << "Bar::Set(const UberFoo&)" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar a, b;

    Foo & pa = a;
    const Foo& rb = b;
    const UberFoo & urb = b;

    cout << "First" << endl;

    pa = rb;

    cout << endl << "Second" << endl;

    pa = urb;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know assignment operator should return Ref to self (to make chaining possible) but this is not the point

Comment: Yes, a copy assignment operator is always defined unless explicitly deleted. If you don't define one, the compiler will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is still generating a *non-templated* `operator=` which the first assignment binds to. In the second assignment, the templated `operator=` is a better candidate (because it involves no cast), so that one is picked.

You can see that by adding the following in your code:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
```

Or forcing the proper template call:

```
pa.operator=<Foo>(b);
```

[The standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) says (emphasis mine):

**12.8 Copying and moving class objects, §12.8/17, page 271:**

> A user-declared copy assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static **non-template member function** of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&

§12.8/18, same page:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared *implicitly*.

Comment: and how does generated signature looks like? when `T` is deduced as `Foo` the signature is the same: `void operator=(const Foo&)` so this is as good as compiler-generated one. Why `T` is not deduced as `Foo`?

Comment: @relaxxx: It may be "as good" as the copy assignment operator, but it is _not_ a copy assignment operator, per the rules quoted in this answer. `T` can be deduced as `Foo` but there is no need for that to occur, since there is already a matching non-template function to invoke and that takes precedence.

Comment: @relaxxx As LRIO said, the signature is the same, but the function is templated. A non-template is a better match than a template during overload resolution, so the deleted operator gets picked as best candidate.

Comment: I've written the comment before you entered the quote from standard (I should wait as you've suggested :). I didn't know that template `operator=` is not actual assignment operator. So now it is clear why it works like this. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

> why the first assignment doesn't call template operator= in Foo, but second does? What is going one here?

Apart from the fact explained by William's answer on implicitly generated copy assignment operator function, overload resolution also has a play in this. Below are the candidates for the first assignment operator, after the template argument substitution, as seen by the compiler:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo&);        // implicitly generated
void operator=(const Foo&);        // template generated
```

All things being equal, nontemplate functions are preferred over function templates. As per C++11 (draft N3337), 13.3.3/1 (emphasis mine)

> Given these definitions, **a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if** for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> — for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
>
> — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
>   standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>   entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>   the return type of F2 to the destination type. [ ... ] or, if not that,
>
> — **F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization**, or, if not that,
>
> — F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized
>   than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

This explains why the non-template overload is picked. You can verify the same with a small exercise:

```
void print(int, int) { std::cout << "int"; }
template <typename T> void print(T, T) { std::cout << "T"; }
print(1, 2); // prints int
print<>(1, 2); // prints T
```

As for the second assignment, it sees

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo&);      // implicitly generated
void operator=(const UberFoo&);  // template generated
```

Here the template generated function is a closer match than the implicitly generated one and thus it was chosen.